# In Ocean Girl Season 2 & 3, are we seeing the same spacecraft?

Tags: ocean-girl

In *Ocean Girl* season 2, Neri and Jason found a spacecraft under the sea, the one in which Neri and her Father came to Earth. Inside that craft, Neri found her father’s Sign.

In season 3, again Jason and Neri found a spacecraft under her island, and they found “Kal” inside.

So in these two seasons (*Ocean Girl* 2 & 3), is it the same spacecraft or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**These are the same spacecraft.**

According  to the [Ocean Girl Archive](http://www.oceangirl.org/archive/html/86.html), this was a continuity error:

> In season 2 Neri and Jason goes into the spaceship and takes some
>   stuff out of it. Then in season 3 when they find an entrance to the
>   spaceship, they appear as if it’s never happened before.